# Toast not showing well when using AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, asp.net, xamarin

I am inherited "AppCompatActivity" activity in my custom activity as shown in code below :

```
public class MyHomeActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
   Toast.MakeText(this, "Email & Message successfully sent at SOS contacts.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

The toast message is not showing well in this activity as shown in the picture below.. please help if anybody have any solution for it....

[image]

Comment: is this the same result in the image is the out come from your code ?

Comment: Dont know if we can inherit **AppCompatActivity** like the code shown here.

Comment: Toast.LENGTH_LONG is java syntax and ToastLength.Long is c# syntax for definning toast length @bhargavthanki don't confuse with it...

Comment: please see the above code now.. @Sree

Comment: Its c# syntax for inheritance @Clairvoyant i think you working on java code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom view for your Toast with a TextView that support multiple lines, this will create a custom view Toast with text that fits in it.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.custom_toast, null);
var txt = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCustomToast);
txt.Text = "your toast message";

var toast = new Toast(this)
    {
        Duration = ToastLength.Short,
        View = view
    };
toast.Show();
```

Also inserting a new line character (i.e \n) into the toast message in your current code, will show the toast message in two lines and also the background will be proper.

Comment: @RanjitBisht you're welcome. Accept the answer if it helped you.